# css margin-block-start, border-inline-end, xxx-(block|inline)-(start|end)

Tags: html, css, padding, inline, margin

is there a `xxx-(block|inline)-(start|end)` for `width` & `height` props?
similar to `margin-(block|inline)-(start|end)`, `padding-(block|inline)-(start|end)`, `border-(block|inline)-(start|end)`.

I want to create a widget that can be oriented horizontally, vertically, reverse-horizontally, etc.
I want to set the `custom width` reflected to the `css width` when the *writting page* in horizontal orientation, but reflected to `css height` when vertical.

Comment: I think there isn't.

Comment: is there a pseudo classes to detect the writing orientation? or any other trick to do that?

Comment: I was wrong, see the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties are [`block-size` and `inline-size`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-logical/#dimension-properties)

Comment: how about background-position ? since left,right,top,bottom will be meaningless for orientation-aware element.

Comment: @YunusKurniawan - There's some properties for that in the [CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-4/#background-position-longhands) draft, but it's very early days and it's not ready for implementation yet.

Answer (score 0):

everyone. I found another interesting css prop:

`inset: 0` is the shorthand of `left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;`.

It has orientation aware too, so if i write `inset-inline: 5px` is equivalent to `left: 5px; right: 5px` for horizontal orientation or `top: 5px; bottom: 5px;` for the vertical one.

Hope this trick useful for your css projects.